# How can I get the derivative of these two functions?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have searched about the derivatives and approximated them by hand but they do not match up to what I am getting when i try to calculate them. Sorry If I cannot annotate them correctly, I hope you can understand my meaning...

Equation 1

$$f(x) = \frac{I}{\sqrt{x/tn}}$$

where $I$ and $tn$ are constants. I have gotten the answer of...

$$f(x) = -\frac{I^2 \cdot tn}{x^2}$$

but it is not adding up when I graph it out...while my hand approximation is much closer

Comment: you mean this here:$$f(x)=\frac{i}{\sqrt{\frac{x}{t_n}}}$$ and $$f(x)=\frac{-i^2\cdot t_n}{x^2}$$?

Comment: Write $f(x)=I \sqrt{tn}\times x^{-1/2}$

Comment: What is 'I' here?

Comment: @SagarMishra `I` and `tn` are constants that are part of the thing I am calculating. They are not dependent on `x` and they are not important here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the tip from above we get for the first derivative $$i\cdot t_n\frac{-1}{2}x^{-3/2}$$
Analogously we can write for the second equation
$$f(x)=-i^2\cdot t_nx^{-2}$$ Thus, we get $$f'(x)=2\cdot i^2\cdot t_nx^{-3}$$ After the exponential rule $$ (x^n)'=nx^{n-1} $$

Comment: I think data is insufficient because it is not given what is $t_n$ and what is I. Do it depend on x or not

Comment: b ut it is given that $$f(x)=...$$

Comment: But it do not mean that I and $t_n$ do not depend on x. They can also be two functions of x

Comment: yes they can, but it will only know the OP

Comment: Sir, what is OP?

Comment: Actually I'm a student of class 12th so I don't have much knowledge as you. I'm in learning process

Comment: I stated in my original post that `I` and `tn` are constants which I thought meant that they were independent of `x`